# How to merge margin notes from an ePub book to a modified version of the same book in GPB

Tags: annotations, google-play-books

I started reading an eBook and doing my normal annotations routine and later on discovered that the book could be greatly improved by adding a table of contents, a cover image, etc. I'm wondering if I modify this book in say Calibre and reupload it to my google play books library how can I apply my notes from the previous upload to the later? I believe it will treat the book as a new instance and not update the original version I previously uploaded, but maybe there's some clever workaround to adapt to the new copy. Might be useful to explore the internals for how GPB represents the indexes for the annotations.